# Big Query - Incrementally update accumulated columns

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

Im having trouble with this problem: I have a table in BigQuery which has columns "day, person_id, daily_margin, running_margin_30d and total_accumulated_margin".
My problem is now the table has became too big to run everyday (I delete and re-create it) but now it consumes too much memory. I´ve been trying to make it update incrementally using a MERGE statement, but I don´t know how to compute the accumulated columns (historically and last 30 days).

So for example if I run it one day I get (last 2 columns are null as I only get daily data):

| day | person_id | daily_margin | running_margin_30d | total_accumulated_margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2nd Jan | 17 | 5 | NULL | NULL |

and suppose the last row of the historical table is

| day | person_id | daily_margin | running_margin_30d | total_accumulated_margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Jan | 17 | 2 | 15 | 40 |

I then need for the updated historical table to look like this after the MERGE:

| day | person_id | daily_margin | running_margin_30d | total_accumulated_margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2nd Jan | 17 | 5 | 20 | 45 |

So we would be summing the new **daily_margin** row to the historical **running_margin_30d** and **total_accumulated_margin**.

Comment: BigQuery != MySQL. Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table to hold the daily data that needs to be merged into the main table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `temp_table_name`
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS
SELECT columns
FROM `main_table`
```

Use a MERGE statement to update the main table with the data from the temporary table.

```
MERGE INTO `main_table` t
USING `temp_table` s
ON t.key = s.key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.column = s.column
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (column_names)
  VALUES (values);
```